# Seaborn doesn't draw all columns in displot

Tags: python-3.x, plot, markdown, seaborn

I try to draw displot with seaborn with this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

trips = pd.read_csv('tripdata_2019-05.csv')

sns.displot(trips, x='week_day')
```

and as result get this plot:

[image: uncorrect plot]

But if I save plot to the file and view it on the markdown in this way:

```
sns.displot(trips, x='week_day')
plt.savefig("graphics/week_day")
plt.close()
```

markdown cell:

```
![](graphics/week_day)
```

I get this correct plot:

[image]

So what the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an aliasing problem with the image. I don't know why the bars are so thin, they are not like that on my computer.

Maybe try to increase the size of the FacetGrid figure?

```
sns.displot(trips, x='week_day', height=6)
```

You could also increase the resolution by adding

```
plt.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 300
```

just before `sns.displot()`

Comment: Maybe it could also help to explicitly set an edge color? Usually matplotlib draws lines with antialiasing, but rectangles without.